# how I can find the radius vector and the velocity vector satellite in elliptic orbits?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, mathematics

In order to evaluate the following expression at each point in an elliptical orbit, I first need the state vector $\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{v}$.

$$
\omega_j=\frac{1}{r^2||\textbf{v} \times \textbf{r}||} \ \textbf{v} \cdot [(\textbf{r} \cdot \textbf{v}) \ \textbf{r}-r^2\textbf{v}]
$$

But how can I find $\textbf{r}, \textbf{v}$ given the following elements?

- Altitude $h$: 543.8832 km
- Period $T$ : 6114 sec
- Eccentricity $e$: 0.0727
- Semi-major axis $a$: 7227.5 km
- Inclination $i$: 81.0192 de

Comment: Okay great, I've added those to your post. *My guess* is that in the end all you'll need is $a$ and $e$ if whatever the scalar quantity $\omega_j$ doesn't depend on the orbital plane. Can you share a bit more information about what it is?

Comment: $\omega_j$ represents the y-component term in $\omega_O^{O/I}=[0,−\omega_j,0]$. and $\omega_O^{O/I}$ is the angular velocity of the Orbit frame relative to the Inertial frame

Comment: You cannot, and this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find the true anomaly of satellites in elliptic orbits?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/58465/how-can-i-find-the-true-anomaly-of-satellites-in-elliptic-orbits)